# Which is the proper algorithm for a fast and stable sort of an array of pointers?

Tags: algorithm, delphi, sorting

I have the following data structure and I want to sort it fast (obvious) and stable. Which algorithm do you think is suitable ?

```
type
  PSuperListItem = ^TSuperListItem;
  TSuperListItem = record
    SubItems  : array of String;
    Marked    : Boolean;
    ImageList : Byte;
    ImageIndex: Integer;
    Data      : Pointer;
  end;

  TSuperListItems = array of PSuperListItem;

var
  Items: TSuperListItems;
```

I found [here](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) that only Insertion, Bubble and Merge sort algorithms are stable. I know that Merge sort is for sorting a linked list. For the other two algorithms I know nothing about, but I have a strange feeling that they are slower. So I don't know which algorithm to use.

Comment: How do you want them sorted. I would go for a Quicksort.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt QuickSort isn't stable.

Comment: A merge sort: [Easy way to add stable sorting to TList and TStringList](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28742123/576719).

Comment: Thank you so much, LU RD ! That MergeSort algorithm works very well. It's stable and faster than QuickSort with 26% at 1,000,000 list items.

Comment: FWIW, there are various stable sorting algorithms. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts). But I assume that merge sort is the fastest of those.

Comment: And one more: [See here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26048/Fastest-In-Place-Stable-Sort). Seems that stable binary quicksort is pretty fast (in the implementation presented there).

Comment: A possible solution is to add an extra field to the array being sorted, where you list the original order. If you add in that field as the least significant part of your sorting key, quicksort will sort in order :-)

Comment: The first hit on google lists this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26048/Fastest-In-Place-Stable-Sort I found that link very illuminating. The code should be easy to translate to Delphi.

Comment: For those who know Basic, but I don't...

Comment: @Marus It's well worth being able to read code in other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a Merge Sort algorithm for Delphi here:
http://alexandrecmachado.blogspot.com/2015/03/merge-sort-for-delphi-revisited.html

It includes a DUnit test project. About performance, in fact it is not slower than Delphi's TList standard Quick Sort algorithm at all. In some cases it can be even faster and my tests show it.

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged here.

Comment: Hi again David! Seems that your crusade downvoting my answers is complete. However, if you read the question closely, you will see that only 2 words are the answer: "Merge Sort". He asks for a fast and stable method do sort his list and my answer more than satisfies it. I think you need help, dude

Comment: I think you should stop reacting personally and try to see the criticism with an objective viewpoint. Here you provide a link to your own code and make no attempt to discuss the merits of the algorithms mentioned in the question. By any measure this does not answer the question. If you don't believe that downvoting should be allowed then you are in the wrong place.

Comment: This is not "a place", dude. I know you think SO is your backyard, but it is not, believe me.

Comment: I don't think it's my back yard, but I do think I understand how SO works. If you have a problem with the concept of down voting, if you feel it should be banned, then you can take that to meta. If you disagree with the guidelines over link only answers, again, take that up on meta.

Answer (score 5):

> I know that Merge sort is for sorting a linked list

It is not true. Mergesort is suitable both for linked list and for arrays.

And yes, Mergesort is faster than Bubble and Insertion sorts, it has complexity O(NlogN) against O(N^2) for mentioned sorts (but requires additional memory). All this information [is available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

What is a size of your arrays? Are complexity issues really important?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, use mergesort.  Mergesort is not only for linked lists.  It can also be used for sorting arrays, but you need to allocate O(n) extra memory to hold the sub-arrays.

Don't use bubble or insertion sort, those are O(n^2) running time.  If you don't want to use up O(n) extra memory, then you are going to have to implement something more complicated.  There are stable versions of quicksort that don't use much extra memory, but they are complicated.  There are also in-place versions of mergesort that don't use much extra memory, but those are also more complicated.

Comment: And I don't know any implementations of in-place MergeSort that don't do a lot of extra move operation that cripple performance.

Comment: Neither do I.  I also don't know of any stable implementations of quicksort that don't use O(n) extra memory.  I've read that both exist, but are complicated, and have large constant factors that make them slow.